# Split column to many columns in PostgresQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a table like:

```
 id     Name   f_data
  1     Raj   {"review":"perfect", "tech":{"scalability":"complete", "backbonetech":["satellite"], "lastmiletech":["Fiber","Wireless","DSL"] }}
```

I want to split f_data column to multiple columns. Expected result:

```
 id     Name    review   scalability   backbonetech   lastmiletech
  1     Raj     perfect    complete      satellite   Fiber,wireless,DSL
```

when I tray split json column I couldn't remove the bracket. My output is:

```
 id  Name  review  scalability backbonetech   lastmiletech
  1  Raj   perfect complete   ["satellite"]   ["Fiber","wireless","DSL"]
```

I used this code:

```
SELECT id, Name,
   f_data->'review' ->>0 as review,
   f_data->'tech' ->> 'scalability' as scalability,
   f_data->'tech' ->> 'backbonetech' as backbonetech,
   f_data->'tech' ->> 'lastmiletech' as lastmileteck
from my_table;
```

Comment: Post the query that you have tried so for

Comment: What result do you want if the array in `geographic` contains 30 elements? Or 5000?

Comment: That is not valid json.  Please post what is really in that column.

Comment: @ Mike Organek I edited the table and also I shared the code that I used. I really appreciate it if you solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use the **json_array_elements_text** function to transform the arrays in your JSON into a set of text and then use the **string_agg** function to concatenate the individual elements into a single string.

For lastmiletech, the request might look like :

```
select
    string_agg(t.lastmiletech, ',') as lastmiletech
from 
(
    select 
       json_array_elements_text('{"scalability":"complete", "backbonetech":>["satellite"], "lastmiletech":["Fiber","Wireless","DSL"]}'::json->'lastmiletech') as lastmiletech
) t
```

You can modify the subquery to include the additional fields you need.

As the name imply, the first parameter of the json_array_elements_text has to be a json array, so be careful not to convert the array into text before passing it to the function. In other words,  `f_data->tech->>lastmiletech` will not be accepted.